# Redrawing circuit diagram for Thevenin's theorem

Tags: thevenin

[image]

We're looking for Uo voltage but that's not the issue (yet). My problem is I don't know how to redraw this diagram in a way so that I'm able to see the resistors connections and compute the equivalent resistance.
I only came up with this
[image]
 but am not sure if you can just invert this upper 2R resistor branch in that way.

Answer (score 1):

And here's another one exactly equivalent to the other fine answer:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbYO65.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The circuit you drew is not correct, as the connection between the resistor are not the same as the circuit from the exercise.

This kind of exercises are designed to teach you to look at schematics and see them quickly redrawn in your head in a more convenient way.

My suggestion is to try to rearrange the posision of the resistor while paying attention to keep the connections of the terminals. You should get something like the following:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOGRQk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As @glen_geek has shown, the circuit looks like a wheatstone-bridge. The thévenin equivalent will be with a Vth = -E/3 and Rth= 4R/3. Now, it´s easy to figure out the remaining part of the exercise.